# Bootstrap in react

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using [react-bootstrap-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-select). But when i run my project, i get an error:

> TypeError: React.__spread is not a function

```
 TypeError: React.__spread is not a function
render
d:/PROJECTS/REACT_APP/bsapp/node_modules/react-bootstrap-select/dist/Select.js:58
  55 |   },
  56 |   render: function () {
  57 |     return (
> 58 |       React.createElement(Input, React.__spread({},  this.props, {type: "select"}))
  59 |     );
  60 |   }
  61 | });
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Please provide your version of React, and the version of react-bootstrap-select.

Answer (score 0):

"[React.__spread has been removed in React 15.x](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7964)"

What is your version of React? The version of react-bootstrap-select that you are using might be incompatible with your version of React.

Comment: I'm using React with 16.0.0. Why when i install module bootstrap by npm, my project an error occurred.

Comment: You cannot use both together. The best thing is to open a github issue at react-bootstrap-select, and if possible, a pull request with the fix proposed by Kuon.

Answer (score 0):

React.__spread has been deprecated in React 15.0: [See this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7270)

In that issue you can read a workaround made by [Kuon](https://github.com/kuon) using Lodash:

```
import {assign} from 'lodash';
(React as any).__spread = assign;
```

I've tried it and works great!
Hope it helps!

Comment: Where do you paste this code? It has to be executed before that of the (npm) module that causes the error.

Comment: You should update original Bootstrap select library! You could also make a pull request

Comment: I have alternative for React.__spread by Object.assign() and  working. Maybe, @JulienD i should have go to github topic. Thank all for supported.